# Having light actionbar in 2.3.6, but dark actionbar in 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm testing an application, and whenever I use it on my 2.3.6 device, I get the white theme, with the white action bar. But when I try it on the emulator with 4.4.2, the actionbar changes to black. Is there any way to make the actionbar always white, in all devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a style based on `Theme.Light` (or `Theme.Holo.Light`) for low api levels, but `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` for API level >= 14.

Check your `res\values-v14\styles.xml` file and change

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

into

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```